# How do I set the taglib character set on Windows to use unicode?

Tags: unicode, build-automation, cmake, taglib

TagLib uses the CMake build system to create the Visual Studio 2010 solution and project files.

The only problem with the generated projects is that the Character Set is set to MBCS, when I'd like it to be Unicode.

Is there a way to set this option via CMake?

I'm currently using this to build taglib on Windows on a VS2010 command prompt:

```
cmake -DWITH_MP4=ON -DENABLE_STATIC=ON .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command should do the job:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=/D_UNICODE ..
```

cmake automatically turns on the Unicode character set in Visual Studio projects if `_UNICODE` macro is defined.

Comment: Makw sure to define both UNICODE and _UNICODE. One affects the Win API, the other affects the CRT functions

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively to Andrey's answer you could specify the character set in a CMakeLists.txt file by

```
target_compile_definitions (TargetName PRIVATE -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE
                                                     <additional defines>)
```

Comment: Should we better set unicode on the cmake projet or on a cmake target?
On a multi target project (say lib + exe) what is the good practice? Unicode is mostly a matter of interface (cmd, screen, files, network...), where should we set this constraint?